# Redirect all domains of .com to .org on a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I need a help on a site redirection, i have 2 domains : mywebsite.com and mywebsite.org, they both point to the same site (wordpress), and the .com is already indexed by google, i want to redirect all *.com links to [www.mysite.org](http://www.mysite.org) links also all non www of .org to [www.mywebsite.org](http://www.mywebsite.org)

I have done like this but nothing works :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.org/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

What i have done wrong here?
thank you

Comment: _“What i have done wrong here?”_ - you are inventing your own variables. `%{HTTPS_HOST}` is not a thing.

Comment: It should be `HTTP_HOST`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.org/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

As noted in comments, `HTTPS_HOST` does not exist, it should be `HTTP_HOST`. So, the above condition will simply fail to match and no redirect occurs.

So, if you correct the above variable then this *should* work to redirect all traffic from `mywebsite.com` to `www.mywebsite.org`, maintaining the URL-path.

However, since this is WordPress, you should avoid manually editing the directives that are part of the front-controller, ie. the code between the `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress` comment markers. Any redirect that you add should go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` block at the top of the `.htaccess file.

This also doesn't redirect the non-www version of the `.org` domain.

If you only have these 2 domains then you can simplify the redirect by checking that the requested hostname is *not* the canonical hostname (ie. is not `www.mywebsite.org`) and redirecting accordingly.

Try the following instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Canonical redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mywebsite\.org$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.org/$1 [R=302,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
<IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* negates the regex, so the condition is only successful when it does not match.

Test with 302 (temporary) redirects and only change to 301 (permanent) when you are sure this is working OK - to avoid potential caching issues.

Make sure you have cleared your browser cache before testing.

Note that you are redirecting to HTTP (not HTTPS) - is that intentional?